# i want to know how jquery' delegate or on(for delegate) works

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

sometimes i use `on` to delegate event ,

```
dom.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.target for hander.
}
instead:
dom.on("click",'a'，function(){
  $(this).handler..
}
```

so,i guess i can write codes in this way :

```
function delegate(dom,event,selector,handler){
   target = event.target;
   while selector.dom.not_match event.target
       target = target.parentNode
       recheck until match the selector and do handler;
   end
}
```

i had wrote this before:

```
function delegate(dom,event,selector,handler){
    dom.addEvent event function(){
      target_arr = dom.find(selector);
      if(event.target in_array target_arr){
        do handler
      }else{
         target = target.parentNode until dom.
         recheck in target_arr;
      }
    }

}
```

someone  know how jquery's work method on 'delegate' or 'on' for delegate?please show me the code simply description for 'delegate'..thanks alot.

Comment: You can grab the development code from jqeury and study from the code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery docs for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), they explain the concept very well.

Also, you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js)!

The lessons learned:

- [`delegate`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L943) is just a wrapper for `on` with different parameter order
- [`on`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L848) does just some parameter normalisation and handles `one`, but delegates then to `jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );`
- [`event.add`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L13) does do a lot of validation, handles multiple types and special cases, pushes the arguments on `$.data("events")` and calls `elem.addEventListener(type, jQuery.event.dispatch, false)`
- [`event.dispatch`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L330) then queries the handles from `$.data("events")` again and builds a [`jqEvent`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L605) from the native event. Then it begins searching for delegated events - [the code for that](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L355) is quite straightforward - and pushes them on the `handlerQueue`, after that the normal handlers which are attached directly on the element. In the end, it just [runs the `handlerQueue`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L386), starting with the delegated handlers.

Comment: get the point,i can't understand why jquery.event.add  doing as that ,so why jquery do this ?so complicated for my imagine..

Comment: Still writing on an explanation... You can jump over the most parts. If you're interested in finding the delegated-events-elements, have a look at [line 350 to 380](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L350)

Comment: thanks a lot ,i founded that ,jquery use match dom and propagation finding too..maby i think on a same line with jq,use parentNode to check out current dom is the delegate in the selector given.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
$(selector1).on(event, selector2, function);
```

jQuery binds a handler to the event on the DOM elements that match `selector1`. When this handler runs, it walks the DOM hierarchy from the most specific element up to the element matching `selector1`, and checks whether any of the elements matches `selector2`. If it finds a match, it calls `function` with the appropriate execution context.

This is how `on()` is able to handle events on DOM elements that are added dynamically after the delegation is created.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.4.2 launch, a new method called `delegate()` was introduced. This method attaches a handler to one or more events for selected/specified elements. Let's take an example. I have created a table and using delegate method, I will attach the click event handler to every td element.

```
<table border="1" width="200px" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
       <td>Item 1</td>
       <td>Item 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Item 3</td>
       <td>Item 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery `delegate()` method code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table").delegate("td","click",function(){
         alert('I am' + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

It takes 3 arguments.

1. Selector
2. Event Type
3. Event Handler

You will say that this is very much possible with the `bind()` method. Below code will serve the purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $("table td").bind("click",function(){
      alert('I am' + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

Then what's new with `delegate()` method?

bind() method will add event to element which are on the page when it was called. For example, there are only 4 td on the page when bind() was called. Later on, when you **dynamically** add more td in the table then bind() will not attach click event handler to those td. Let's extend our demo and place a button on the page which will add the td dynamically.

```
<input type="button" value="Add TD" id="btnAdd" />

$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
   $("table").append("<tr><td>Item 5</td><td>Item 6</td></tr>");
});
```

Now, when you run this page, you will not find click event for newly added td.

But with `delegate()`, you will find click event for newly added td. delegate() method adds event which are on the page and also listens for new element and add event to them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Click a paragraph to add another. Note that .delegate() attaches a click event handler to all paragraphs - even new ones.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <style>
              p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; 
                  padding:5px; }
              p.over { background: #ccc; }
              span { color:red; }
              </style>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <p>Click me!</p>

              <span></span>
            <script>
                $("body").delegate("p", "click", function(){
                  $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
                });
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

another example

```
              <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <style>
              p { color:red; }
              span { color:blue; }
              </style>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <p>Has an attached custom event.</p>
              <button>Trigger custom event</button>
              <span style="display:none;"></span>
            <script>

                $("body").delegate("p", "myCustomEvent", function(e, myName, myValue){
                  $(this).text("Hi there!");
                  $("span").stop().css("opacity", 1)
                           .text("myName = " + myName)
                           .fadeIn(30).fadeOut(1000);
                });
                $("button").click(function () {
                  $("p").trigger("myCustomEvent");
                });

            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

working of methods 
for  version added: 1.4.2

.delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject) )

selector- A selector to filter the elements that trigger the event.

eventType- A string containing one or more space-separated JavaScript event types, such as "click" or "keydown," or custom event names.

handler(eventObject)- A function to execute at the time the event is triggered.

for version added: 1.4.2

delegate( selector, eventType, eventData, handler(eventObject) )

selector- A selector to filter the elements that trigger the event.

eventType- A string containing one or more space-separated JavaScript event types, such as "click" or "keydown," or custom event names.
eventData A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

handler(eventObject)- A function to execute at the time the event is triggered.

for version added: 1.4.3

delegate( selector, events )

selector- A selector to filter the elements that trigger the event.

events- A map of one or more event types and functions to execute for them.

Comment: This is just a copy of the jQuery documentation.

Comment: igaves you have to go through jquery.com it will solve your problem

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").delegate("p","click",function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","pink");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color:yellow">
<p>This is a paragraph inside a div element.</p>
</div>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```