# Check if image was clicked JQuery

Tags: javascript, image, click

I want to know how to check if my image was clicked using jquery...

Here is my html code

```
<img class="img-fade" src="img/message.png" id="messages" />
```

And my jquery code im using:

```
$('#messages').on("click", "img", function (e) { alert('hi'); }
```

But it still isnt working,

Could anyone help? Thanks :D

Comment: your code seems fine, just check in the browser console that if you're getting some scripting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
$(selector1).on(event, selector2, function);
```

jQuery binds a handler to the event on the DOM elements that match selector1. When this handler runs, it walks the DOM hierarchy from the most specific element up to the element matching selector1, and checks whether any of the elements matches selector2. If it finds a match, it calls function with the appropriate execution context.

This is how on() is able to handle events on DOM elements that are added dynamically after the delegation is created.

[i want to know how jquery' delegate or on(for delegate) works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985243/i-want-to-know-how-jquery-delegate-or-onfor-delegate-works)

In your case you made selector1 and selector2 the same element which caused trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#messages').on("click", function (e) {
        $('.content2').fadeOut(3000);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = 'messagecenter.html';
        }, 3050);
    });
});
```

I just fixed it :)
Instead of having `$('#var').on("click", "img", function(e)) {});`
I just removed the `"img"` part which I don't think was needed.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too

```
$('#messages').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but the click function isn't as good as using the on(params) function